# Efficient and transparentl caching layer with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

We have about 90% of data requested by the user that stays the same between page reloads, and we would really like to be able to cache a thoses objects.

For example, for a Time Series app, only recent Series get new events.

Is anyone aware of a currently efficient way to enable cache for some queries that can leverage the power of Live queries/subscribers?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to cache this data in the client side or in the server side?

Comment: In the client side. Probably in localStorage

Comment: Parse JS SDK has built-in features to store, retrieve data from the local datastore. Have you looked at this? https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#local-datastore

Comment: I looked at it but maybe it was some old docs that were mentioning it was not available for the Web, and only within Apps

Comment: It should work for web as well. Give it a try and let me know in the case you have any issue.